# Can I embed my GraphQL schema into a vector database like Pinecone and get LLM to generate the query/mutations?

Tags: graphql, embedding, openai-api

I am experimenting with a new UI where typical profile settings are updated via chat instead of UI. For example, instead of showing a frontend component to let users cancel their billing, they can just chat to the bot.

I am wondering if its possible to get my LLM (lets say gpt3) to generate the graphql query necessary to run these operation. I am thinking I could ingest my graphql schema into a vector database like Pinecone, then feed in that context into LLM so that it can generate the appropriate GQL query/mutation.

Is this feasible, or a bad idea?

I have only theorized this so far

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also trying to solve a similar problem and this feels like a good way to fit larger schemas inside models' context limit.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this on simple queries by using Langchain's graphql agent